# Using geemap to apply Otsu's threshold on time series NDVI slope

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, time-series, geemap, otsu

I'm running geemap on Google Colab, and try to apply Otsu's threshold to a Sentinel-2 time series NDVI, the threshold is when the NDVI slope is greater than 0.5.

But when I try to apply the otsu function to the ndvi slope data, the code is: `"s2_ndvi_by_year_mean_slope_otsu = s2_ndvi_by_year_mean_slope.map(lambda image: otsu(image))"`.
It gave me the error:

> 'Image' object has no attribute 'map'

Should I change the object from image to another form or should the Otsu function be modified? And frankly, I don't know how to do so.
Also, since the next line is:

```
s2_ndvi_by_year_mean_slope_otsu_filtered = s2_ndvi_by_year_mean_slope_otsu.map(lambda image: image.updateMask(image.gte(0.5)))
```

Should I modify it too?
The colab notebook link is: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1yAaZMfEfM0iOazAbcIRaSxpBCyWUgroJ?usp=sharing

I also provide the code below:

```
import ee
import geemap

# Initialize Earth Engine
#ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()

# Define a function to calculate the slope of an image
def calculateSlope(image):
    # Get the coefficients of a linear fit to the image
    fit = image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.linearFit(), roi, 10)
    # Extract the slope
    slope = fit.get('scale')
    # Return the slope as a new image
    return image.select(['ndvi']).multiply(ee.Image.constant(slope)).rename('ndvi_slope')

# Define a function to apply the Otsu thresholding algorithm to an image
def otsu(image):
    # Get the histogram data
    values = image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.histogram(10), roi, 10).get('nd')

    # Variables for calculating threshold
    total = ee.Number(image.multiply(10).reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.sum(), roi, 10).get('nd'))
    sumB = ee.Number(0)
    wB = ee.Number(0)
    maximum = ee.Number(0)
    threshold = ee.Number(0)

    # Loop through all possible threshold values
    for i in range(256):
        wB = wB.add(values.get(i))
        if wB.neq(0):
            wF = total.subtract(wB)
            if wF.neq(0):
                sumB = sumB.add(ee.Number(i).multiply(values.get(i)))
                mB = sumB.divide(wB)
                mF = (total.subtract(sumB)).divide(wF)
                between = wB.multiply(wF).multiply(mB.subtract(mF).pow(2))
                if between.gt(maximum):
                    maximum = between
                    threshold = ee.Number(i)

    # Return the threshold as a new image
    return image.gt(threshold).rename('threshold')

# Define the region of interest
roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-122.4072265625, 37.74972527434998],
      [-121.640625, 37.74972527434998],
      [-121.640625, 38.49816001144048],
      [-122.4072265625, 38.49816001144048],
      [-122.4072265625, 37.74972527434998]]],
    None, False
)

# Load the Sentinel-2 image collection
s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')

# Filter the collection by date and region of interest
s2_filtered = s2.filterDate('2019-01-01', '2021-12-31').filterBounds(roi)

# Define a function to calculate NDVI from an image
def calculateNDVI(image):
    ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('ndvi')
    return image.addBands(ndvi)

# Calculate NDVI for each image in the collection
s2_ndvi = s2_filtered.map(calculateNDVI)

# Calculate the slope of NDVI for each year in the collection
s2_ndvi_by_year = s2_ndvi.map(lambda image: image.set('year', ee.Date(image.date()).get('year')))
s2_ndvi_by_year_mean = s2_ndvi_by_year.select('ndvi').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).rename('ndvi_mean')

s2_ndvi_by_year_mean_slope = s2_ndvi_by_year_mean.select('ndvi_mean') \
    .reduce(ee.Reducer.linearFit()) \
    .select('slope') \
    .rename('ndvi_mean_slope')
    # Print the resulting image
#print(s2_ndvi_by_year_mean_slope)

# Apply the Otsu thresholding algorithm to the NDVI slope time series
s2_ndvi_by_year_mean_slope_otsu = s2_ndvi_by_year_mean_slope.map(lambda image: otsu(image))

# Filter the NDVI slope images with values greater than 0.5
s2_ndvi_by_year_mean_slope_otsu_filtered = s2_ndvi_by_year_mean_slope_otsu.map(lambda image: image.updateMask(image.gte(0.5)))

# Create a visualization of the filtered NDVI slope images
vis_params = {'palette': 'blue,green,yellow,orange,red'}
geemap.ee_tile_layer(s2_ndvi_by_year_mean_slope_otsu_filtered, vis_params, 'NDVI Slope Otsu Filtered').add_to(map)
```

Comment: `.map()` method is for applying a function for every image inside an image collection. `s2_ndvi_by_year_mean_slope` is an image, not an image collection. Use `otsu(s2_ndvi_by_year_mean_slope)`

Comment: Thank you for your help! I changed the code but the error now is `'ComputedObject' object has no attribute 'get'`. When try to run the `otsu` function, the code that returns error is `wB = wB.add(values.get(i)).` It's inside the `otsu` function when try to do the loop.